# Delay non-animatable css properties

Tags: html, css

I have an animation that overflows the body, while both the situations before and after the animation don't (necessarily). I could set `overflow:hidden;` on `body` (which I set to be as high as the viewport), but if the content actually does overflow the body, I want scrollbar to appear at the end of the animation.

I thought a solution would be setting `transition:overflow 0s ease 0.5s`, to delay the overflow property so everything would be hidden during the animation, and would be set to `initial` or `visible` after the animation ended, so the scrollbar only appears if needed. But of course, this doesn't work, since `overflow` is not an animatable property. My question is; can I delay non-animatable properties with pure css?

Comment: Basically...you can't. If it's not animatable that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, **not with pure html/css**, Long answer, you *could sort of replicate this*

You could use something like a max-height property to replicate something like this, although again this feels quite 'hackish' since you'd be setting the max-height to something that will definitely fit all text.

```css
.test {
  max-height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s, max-height 3s 5s;
}
.test:hover {
  background: blue;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">I am only a set width. Hover me to see some magic! I am only a set width. Hover me to see some magic! I am only a set width. Hover me to see some magic!</div>
```

---

An alternative, if possible, would be to use a short script to do this. A sample would be to use `setTimeout` method or similar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.test').addClass("hovered");
    }, 3000);

  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.test:hover {
  background: blue;
}
.hovered {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">I am only a set width. Hover me to see some magic! I am only a set width. Hover me to see some magic!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't a proper way but setting the default opacity to 0 and on hover opacity to 1 with transition can achieve the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

i had similar problem:

```
.test {
 transition: all 1s ease;
 overflow:hidden;
 max-height: 0;
}
.test.withAnimation {
 max-height: 300px;
}
.test.withAnimation:after {
 overflow:inherit;
}
```